# How to Post an image To Facebook Wall using New Fbconnect Api?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, fbconnect

I successfully posted an image along with text to a Facebook Wall using the old Fbconnect Api.  But Now The Old Fbconnect Api doesn't work for me.  Here is my code that I'm using. [Download](http://www.hilbert1862.com/Samplecode/FbTestApp.zip) 
 I  integrated the new Fbconnect api from a different tutorial but I cannot get it to work.  I have three problems with this sample code.

1. How to integrate New Fbconnect Api .
2. How to post an image along With text On user's Facebook Wall as I am using in this sample code.
3. How to post an image along With text On specific Friend's Facebook Wall.

But I request to all who want to help me to please use my code to make all Changes.
Any help will be appriated  .Thanx in advance.

Comment: 50 points isn't really a big payoff for custom code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the grapAPI of FB to post images on FB wall This is the easiest way to dol this Use [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API) link to implement it.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: thanx @Aalok Parikh for helping me.please Check my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOur Image url"];
> NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
> UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
> ```
>
> [variables setObject:img forKey:@"picture"];
>
> FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph
>   doGraphPost:@"/me/photos" withPostVars:variables];